# step function to N times for a task

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, aws-cdk

I am finding a way to do this in , My scenario is I want to repeat a step until I am not finished my dynamic number of files processing in step function for example

```
step1 -> step2 -> step2 -> step2 -> step3 -> done
```

step 2 will be dependent on number of files I needed as output from step 1 . `like If I get 30 files I want to divide these files in 2 chunks and run step2 for 3 times not 30 times`  so how I can make a state machine (preferably in python ckd) . any clue even in json would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT** after searching I came to know we call it map task like mentioned here   `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html` but not getting how I can done this using cdk .

for example if my lambda look like this :

```
 sfn_step_1 = tasks.LambdaInvoke(self, "step1",
                                        lambda_function=step1_lambda,
                                        output_path="$.Payload",
                                        payload=stepfunctions.TaskInput.from_object({
                                            "payload.$": "$",
                                            "execution_id.$": "$$.Execution.Id",
                                            "taskToken.$": "$$.Task.Token"
                                        })
                                        )
        sfn_step_2 = tasks.LambdaInvoke(self, "step2",
                                        lambda_function=step2_lambda,
                                        output_path="$.Payload",
                                        payload=stepfunctions.TaskInput.from_object({
                                            "payload.$": "$",
                                            "execution_id.$": "$$.Execution.Id",
                                            "taskToken.$": "$$.Task.Token"
                                        })
                                        )
        sfn_step_3 = tasks.LambdaInvoke(self, "step3",
                                        lambda_function=step3_lambda,
                                        output_path="$.Payload",
                                        payload=stepfunctions.TaskInput.from_object({
                                            "payload.$": "$",
                                            "execution_id.$": "$$.Execution.Id"
                                        })
                                        )

        state_machine_definition = sfn_step_1.next(sfn_step_2).next(sfn_step_3)
```

like in this I want to repeat step2 multiple times depending upon number of records I get from step2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote here an example of implementing a map in the step functions. I hope it will be helpful.

```
from aws_cdk import aws_stepfunctions
import aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions_tasks as tasks
from aws_cdk import aws_lambda
...
...
...
        self.get_files = aws_lambda.Function(
            self,
            ...
        )
        # should retrun list of the files like below:
        # return [{"file": "file1"}, {"file": "file2"}...]
        
        self.task_2 = aws_lambda.Function(
            self,
            ...
        )

        self.get_files_task = tasks.LambdaInvoke(
            self,
            lambda_function=self.get_files,
            result_path="$.File_List",
            output_path="$",
        )
        self.map_state = aws_stepfunctions.Map(
            self,
            max_concurrency=1,
            items_path=aws_stepfunctions.JsonPath.string_at("$.File_List.Payload"),
            result_path="$.Single.File",
        )
        self.start_task_2 = tasks.LambdaInvoke(self, id="name", lambda_function=self.task_2)

        self.map_state.iterator(self.start_task_2)
        self.definition = self.get_files_task.next(self.map_state)
        self.state_machine = aws_stepfunctions.StateMachine(self, "example", definition=self.definition)
```

Comment: hi thanks for reply . I have few questions first can you tell where you are specifying sequence ? like this is 1st step -> then 2nd (which will repeat) - >  last and the third step . as i did in my code this way   `state_machine_definition = sfn_step_1.next(sfn_step_2).next(sfn_step_3)`

Comment: and can you please explain a little about attributes of Map() function ?

Comment: sequence: `self.definition = self.get_files_task.next(self.map_state)` - (1st step == get_files). I'm not sure how to pass third step, so you need to try different implementations. regarding map: [map](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html)

Comment: hi that worked . just a little question can I make chunks of like 5,5 and run 2nd step function . like in case of 10 records if I want to run 2nd lambda just 2 times to save cost ?

Answer (score 1):

What about "choice" after the step 2.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions.Choice.html

something like this

```
  .next(new sfn.Choice(this, 'Repeat step2 ?')
    // Look at the "status" field
    .when(sfn.Condition.stringEquals('$.status', 'REPEAT'), step2)
    .when(sfn.Condition.stringEquals('$.status', 'MOVE_ON'), step3)
```

Comment: seems fine aswell . is there any benefit to use it over  map() ?  and what is this expecting as input ?  like json in form of  `{"status" : "REPEAT" }` this ?

Comment: Map is to iterate over entries in an array, Choice is to make an decision based on input.

Two different use cases.

Step 2 has to give back a json for the step function. So Step2 can decide where to write specific parameter, and then the choice checks for this specific parameter.

Comment: got it . and input in which format I have to submit choice ? and can I pass my file string as well in choice ? as I will be sending file to step 2 when repeating ? It seems I will have to use maps as I will be sending input aswell which is file path

Comment: As i said before, map is for iteration of elements in array, not for "If Then" logic :) 

You are of course free to use what ever you want and I'm sure you will find a way :) ! 

Now about the check in Choice state. 

I unfortunately don't understand what you mean with "file string".

Do you mean the json, that is passed from step to step ?  

The Choice is testing what you tell him to test :) 

With $ you access the json that has been passed from step to step, and with $$ you access the initial json.